# Routes with :any for 2nd argument in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a mini-ecommerce system. I have 2 entities: 1) User; 2) Admin; I used routes for my tabs so that I won't show the name of the controller and the method(like user/about).

Scenaio:

```
I have 4 tabs, Home, Menu, Contact, About
```

When I clicked the Menu all the menus will be display. The url will look like this, I used :any for this route

```
project/order/menu(name of the selected menu)
```

But when I click again to any those tabs, it will now give me an error because the 3rd segment is for the selected menu only

Question: I would like to do is, I want to prevent the project/order/home and etc. I only want project/order/menu.

Scenario:

```
I am in the menu. The available menu are: Bacon and Chicken
I chose the bacon, it will redirect to project/order/bacon. Then from that 
url I want to transfer to another page for example home. Instead of project/order/home it will look like this project/
```

**Routes**

```
$route['order/(:any)'] = 'user/order/$1';
```

Comment: To fix what? You've described how your app works, not what doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

In /config/routes.php, try putting

```
 $route['home'] = 'project/order/home';
 $route['contact'] = 'project/order/contact';
 $route['about'] = 'project/order/about';
```

above

```
 $route['order/(:any)'] = 'user/order/$1';
```